# Undefined symbols in libav when compiling as C++, but not as C

Tags: c++, linker, libav

I am trying to compile some simple code using the libav libraries.

```
// Some simple code to demonstrate
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    av_register_all();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm on a Mac, with gcc version 4.2.1.

When I try to compile the code as C using

```
gcc -o main main.c -lavformat
```

then the code compiles and links fine. However, when I try to compile it as C++ using

```
g++ -o main main.cpp -lavformat
```

it gives me undefined symbols errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "av_register_all()", referenced from:
      _main in ccQ23HMe.o
```

When I run with the `-v` option, the linking steps run are:

```
// gcc
"/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o c
 /var/folders/r0/n22t1hyn7ts92jxgd9_pn8yw0000gn/T/main-uUfZkM.o -lavformat
-lSystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a

// g++
"/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o c
 /var/folders/r0/n22t1hyn7ts92jxgd9_pn8yw0000gn/T/main-5QU6fj.o -lavformat
 -lstdc++ -lSystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/4.1/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a
```

Here, the only difference is the addition of `-lstdc++` to the linking.

Why are these undefined symbol errors appearing? Is there some reason that simply adding a library to the linking would cause these undefined symbols? Or is there something else that is causing this problem, perhaps specifically related to libavformat?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot use g++ for compiling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439355/cannot-use-g-for-compiling)

Comment: @PaulR: Not really. That's a completely different library, though the answers are the same in both cases.

Comment: -1: Read the library's documentation next time. I found that FAQ in under a minute... :(

Comment: Well it's a common problem with C libraries in C++ programs - I don't think we need a separate question for every single third party library that this applies to ?

Comment: @PaulR: That presupposes that the OP already knew it was a C-only library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *libav* "Frequently Asked Questions" list [covers this *exact* scenario](http://libav.org/faq.html#I_0027m-using-Libav-from-within-my-C_002b_002b-application-but-the-linker-complains-about-missing-symbols-which-seem-to-be-available_002e)!

> Here, the only difference is the addition of -lstdc++ to the linking.

Nope — that, and you're using a different language with different default calling conventions.

`av_register_all` as declared in the header is not marked `extern "C"`, whereas the definition in the actual compiled library requires good old-fashioned C calling convention.

Surround your *libav* includes with `extern "C"`.

Comment: :( Thank you. I've found examples that used the library in a C++ context, so I didn't realize this was necessary. I'll accept when it lets me.

Comment: It is common practice for polite authors of C libraries to add the extern "C" to their public headers if __cplusplus is defined. The authors of libavcodec chose not to, but that's probably why it caught you off guard.